# Image Uploading and Previewing with Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know a good plugin to upload and preview an image using jquery....? I've been googling this for a long time and still can't find any....!!!

Thanks and Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty neat script to upload an image using php. javascript and ajax...

Here's the link...The script is pretty neat... You can preview the image before the final upload... Hope it will be useful for others...

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=209720

Thanks and Regards...

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload using only javascript, so you won't find anything with jQuery. Using AJAX you can lookup these :

[jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)

[jQuery Multiple Files Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

If jQuery is not a total requirement, try also looking up [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/).

Comment: Hello Marc... i'm aware that uploading can't be done with javascript alone... i just thought jquery is pretty capable of doing it with it's  ajax functions....

Comment: Yes, I gave you two links of plugins capables of doing this